# undefined symbol: _PyThreadState_Current when using pybind wrapped C++ code

Tags: python, c++, bazel, pybind11

When I'm running `bazel test ...` the cpp code will compile, but Python gets stuck.
I read these before I wrote this question, but I can not find any solution:

https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/314

[undefined symbol: _PyThreadState_Current when importing tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002315/undefined-symbol-pythreadstate-current-when-importing-tensorflow)

https://github.com/carla-simulator/ros-bridge/issues/368

https://python-forum.io/thread-32297.html

OS:
`Linux 5.11.0-43-generic #47~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 13 11:06:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Python: `Python 3.8.10`

g++: `g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`

pybind11: `v2.8.1`

C++ Code:

```cpp
//math.cc
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
  return i + j;
}

int subtract(int i, int j) {
  return i - j;
}

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(math, m) {
  m.def("add", &add);

  m.def("subtract", &subtract);
}
```

Python code:

```py
#math_test.py
from module import t_math

assert t_math.add(1, 1) == 2
assert t_math.subtract(1, 1) == 0
```

BUILD :

```py
load("@pybind11_bazel//:build_defs.bzl", "pybind_extension")

pybind_extension(
  name = "t_math",
  srcs = ["math.cc"],
)
    
py_test(
  python_version = "PY3",
  name = "math_test",
  size = "small",
  srcs = ["math_test.py"],
  data = [":t_math.so"],
)
```

error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/a768e2cde210bf677ee66cfded678e04/sandbox/linux-sandbox/52/execroot/**main**/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/module/math_test.runfiles/**main**/module/math_test.py",
> line 7, in 
> from module import t_math ImportError: /home/user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_user/a768e2cde210bf677ee66cfded678e04/sandbox/linux-sandbox/52/execroot/**main**/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/module/math_test.runfiles/**main**/module/t_math.so:
> undefined symbol: _PyThreadState_Current

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems:

1. the first parameter of the `PYBIND11_MODULE` macro must be the same as in the `pybind_extension`
2. this environment variable must be set to: `PYTHON_BIN_PATH=$(which python3)`

fixed example

```py
# BUILD
load("@pybind11_bazel//:build_defs.bzl", "pybind_extension")

pybind_extension(
  name = "new_math",
  srcs = ["ex.cpp"],
)
    
py_test(
  python_version = "PY3",
  name = "math_test",
  size = "small",
  srcs = ["math_test.py"],
  data = ["new_math.so"],
)
```

```cpp
// ex.cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
  return i + j;
}

int subtract(int i, int j) {
  return i - j;
}

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(new_math, m) {
  m.def("add", &add);

  m.def("subtract", &subtract);
}
```

```py
# math_test.py
from module import new_math

assert new_math.add(1, 1) == 2
assert new_math.subtract(1, 1) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I also meet a problem like this when I use pybind11.

```
ImportError: dlopen(./lib/example1.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyThread_tss_alloc
  Referenced from: ./lib/example1.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

At last, I found the question is:
I add this below

```
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

in the front of
`find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)`

so, delete it or move it to back, then make it!