# Tensorflow 15.2 with Python 3.7.3 running in raspberry pi 4

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I have python 3.7.3 and Tensorflow 15.2 installed in raspberry pi 4. When I tried to do import Tensorflow as TD, it failed to load the native Tensorflow runtimes. Can you please help and advise how to resolve the following issue?

```
pi@raspberrypi:
  ~ $ python Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44) [GCC 8.3.0] on linux Type "help", 
  "copyright", 
  "credits" or "license" for more information.

import tensorflow as tf Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", 
  line 58, 
    in from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * 
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", 
  line 28, 
    in _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", 
  line 24, 
    in swig_import_helper _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description) File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", 
  line 242, 
    in load_module return load_dynamic(name, filename, file) File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", 
  line 342, 
    in load_dynamic return _load(spec) 
  ImportError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: 
    undefined symbol: _PyThreadState_Current
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "", 
    line 1, 
  in File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/init.py", 
    line 24, 
  in from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow # pylint: disable=unused-import File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/init.py", 
    line 49, 
  in from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", 
    line 74, 
  in raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: 
     Traceback (most recent call last): 
     File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", 
    line 58, 
  in from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", 
    line 28, 
  in _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", 
    line 24, 
  in swig_import_helper _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', 
  fp, 
  pathname, description) File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", 
    line 242, 
  in load_module return load_dynamic(name, filename, file) File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", 
    line 342, 
  in load_dynamic return _load(spec) ImportError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: 
    undefined symbol: _PyThreadState_Current

  Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common reasons and solutions. Included the entire stack trace above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Can you check these similar issues ? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33872#issuecomment-548434341   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002315/undefined-symbol-pythreadstate-current-when-importing-tensorflow